# How to skip first letters from \jobname in plain Tex

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

As intentioned in the title I want a macro `\skipfirstletters` in plain-TeX, that skips the first letters (catcode 11) from the \jobname. 
For instance if the TeX-file is named **Test0xy.tex** it should expand to just **0xy**.

I tried the following lines as **Test0xy.tex**:

```
\def\skipfirstletters#1{\ifcat A#1\expandafter\skipfirstletters\else#1\fi}
\skipfirstletters Test0xy\par
\skipfirstletters\jobname\par
\expandafter\skipfirstletters\jobname

\bye
```

The result is just
[image: 0xy Test0xy Test0xy]

I don't understand alot, e.g. why the expanded `\jobname` in Line 4 (is it expanded before `\skipfirstletters`?) does not behave like the plain tokens in Line 2.

I want to use the expanded macro as argument for others if this matters.

Thanks a lot to the community and sorry for my poor knowledge of TeX.

Comment: the tokens in jobname are all catcode 12 or 10

Comment: 12 ok, but why 10? i thought catcode 10 means "spaces"...

Comment: If a space character somehow creeps in `\jobname`, its category code will be 10.

Comment: All characters in `\jobname` have catcode 12 (other) to avoid trouble with special characters like ``\`` or `%` in it. The only exception is the space. I guess this is because file name strings once saved internally do not have catcodes anymore, as there are not material to be typeset but to be used internally. If you reinsert them into the typeset content a neutral catcode is selected to be on the save side, I guess. *The TeXBook* surely states the reason.

Answer (score 6):

the tokens in `\jobname` are like `\string` and have catcode 12 (or 10 if it is a space), however you can still test the catcode settings for the slots to test whether it is a letter or not:

```
\def\skipfirstletters#1{%
\ifnum11=\catcode`#1 \expandafter\skipfirstletters\else#1\fi}
\skipfirstletters Test0xy\par
\expandafter\skipfirstletters\jobname\par
\expandafter\skipfirstletters\jobname

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

An `expl3` based answer that automatically checks whether `\skipfirstletters` is a macro and doesn't eat what follows because the string to be cut is passed as an argument.

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \skipfirstletters #1
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n { #1 } } { \token_if_cs_p:N #1 }
   {
    \egreg_skipfirstletters:o { #1 }
   }
   {
    \egreg_skipfirstletters:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \egreg_skipfirstletters:n #1
 {
  \__egreg_skipfirstletters:N #1 \q_nil
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_skipfirstletters:n { o }

\cs_new:Npn \__egreg_skipfirstletters:N #1
 {
  \quark_if_nil:NF #1
   {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \char_value_catcode:n { `#1 } } = { 11 }
     {% check the next one
      \__egreg_skipfirstletters:N
     }
     {% output the character and the rest
      #1 \__egreg_skipfirstletters_end:w
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__egreg_skipfirstletters_end:w #1 \q_nil { #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\edef\fakejobname{\detokenize{Test0xy}}

\skipfirstletters{Test0xy}

\skipfirstletters{\fakejobname}

X\skipfirstletters{abc}X

\edef\test{\skipfirstletters{Test0xy}} {\tt\meaning\test}

\edef\test{\skipfirstletters{\fakejobname}} {\tt\meaning\test}

\bye
```

Here `\fakejobname` is defined so I don't have to rename the file to make tests: with `\detokenize` we get the same result as `\jobname, that is, all characters are category code 12 except for spaces that keep category code 10.

[image]

Comment: I should release the `expl3` version that stores Unicode character class in the format (or loads it as needed in plain) ;)